# The html, css, javascript are not responsive when using mobile phone

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive

Can anyone help me make this code responsive?
I added the line of code `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">` like on w3school (https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_responsive.asp) but the countdown cannot detect when I use mobile phone.

```js
// Set the date we're counting down to
var countDownDate = new Date("Nov 27, 2020 00:00:00").getTime();

// Update the count down every 1 second
var x = setInterval(function() {

  // Get today's date and time
  var now = new Date().getTime();
    
  // Find the distance between now and the count down date
  var distance = countDownDate - now;
    
  // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
  var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
  var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
  var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
    
    document.getElementById("day").innerHTML = "<br />" + days + "<br />"+ "Ngày";
    document.getElementById("hour").innerHTML = "<br />" + hours + "<br />" + "Giờ";
    document.getElementById("minute").innerHTML = "<br />" + minutes + "<br />" + "Phút";
    document.getElementById("second").innerHTML = "<br />" + seconds + "<br />" + "Giây";
}, 1000);
```

```css
body, html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
.bgimg {
  background-image: url('https://training.leadthechange.asia/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/MINDFUL-1536x864.png');
  height: 100%;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
  color: black;
  font-family: "Courier New", Courier, monospace;
  font-size: 25px;
}

.middle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 90%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
 .circle {
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    font-size: 30px;
    background: #333333;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
  }
```

```html
<div class="bgimg">
  <div class="middle">
  <div class="circle"><span id="day"></span></div>
  <div class="circle"><span id="hour"></span></div>
  <div class="circle"><span id="minute"></span></div>
  <div class="circle"><span id="second"></span></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The picture is okay, but the countdown in days, hours, minutes, seconds are not responsive

Comment: Do you mean width and height of the countdown?

Comment: you're right, it's not reponsive when using on mobile phone

Comment: By using media queries we can make countdown responsive. 

Try this:
/* Here 767px means viewport width */
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
.circle {
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    font-size: 18px;
}
/* Below css is to beautify only */
.middle {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
}

Answer (score 0):

By using media queries we can make countdown responsive.

Try this:

```
/* Here 767px means viewport width */
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
.circle { 
width: 80px; 
height: 80px; 
font-size: 18px; 
}

/* Below css is to beautify only */ 
.middle { 
width: 100%;
text-align: center;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be made responsive by adjusting the parent div. I've tried to solve your question [here](https://codepen.io/ni_l/pen/QWEyMze). For a full page view, click [here](https://codepen.io/ni_l/full/QWEyMze). Code-

```js
// Set the date we're counting down to
var countDownDate = new Date("Nov 27, 2020 00:00:00").getTime();

// Update the count down every 1 second
var x = setInterval(function() {

  // Get today's date and time
  var now = new Date().getTime();
    
  // Find the distance between now and the count down date
  var distance = countDownDate - now;
    
  // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
  var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
  var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
  var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
    
    document.getElementById("day").innerHTML = "<br />" + days + "<br />"+ "Ngày";
    document.getElementById("hour").innerHTML = "<br />" + hours + "<br />" + "Giờ";
    document.getElementById("minute").innerHTML = "<br />" + minutes + "<br />" + "Phút";
    document.getElementById("second").innerHTML = "<br />" + seconds + "<br />" + "Giây";
}, 1000);
```

```css
html { 
  background: url(https://training.leadthechange.asia/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/MINDFUL-1536x864.png) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  color: black;
  font-family: "Courier New", Courier, monospace;
  font-size: 25px;
}

.parent {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.middle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
 .circle {
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    font-size: 30px;
    background: #333333;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
  }
```

```html
<div class = "parent">
  <div class="middle">
  <div class="circle"><span id="day"></span></div>
  <div class="circle"><span id="hour"></span></div>
  <div class="circle"><span id="minute"></span></div>
  <div class="circle"><span id="second"></span></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

(If you want to reduce the size of circles and its text, you can use media query as pointed out by others! But usually reducing the overall size of elements for mobile devices is a bad idea as there'll be a visibility issue.)